# ParseUser.LogInAsync() exception with unity5 on ios build

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

Im using Unity 5 and parse for login for my ios game.

I can log in in the editor, Android and web player builds, but for some reason when trying to log in on an ios device I get a "System.AggregateException" exception.

The following is my login method:

```
void authenticateUser(string username, string password)
{
    ErrorString = "Logging in...";
    errorTimer = 0;
    ParseUser.LogInAsync(username, password).ContinueWith(t =>
                                                          {
        if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
        {
            // The login failed. Check t.Exception to see why.
            ErrorString = "Error logging in:\n"+t.Exception.Message;
            errorTimer = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Login was successful.
            isAuthenticated = true;
            ErrorString = "Login sucessfull";
            errorTimer = 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue : http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-api-authentication.306566/ and here http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-parse-ios-nsurlerrordomain-error-1012.308569/

You can do a downgrade in Unity or wait this fix